# Improve time complexity of this algorithm

Tags: python, time-complexity, cosine-similarity

I have N pairs of string lists (N from set 1 to N from set 2) that need to be paired to the closest one through the Jaccard similarity. That means that I need to compute N^2 distances and take for each element in set 1 the maximum similarity w.r.t. set 2.

A simple code to run it would be

```
import numpy as np

def jaccard_similarity(a, b):
    intersection = set(a).intersection(set(b))
    union = set(a).union(set(b))
    return len(intersection)/len(union)

set_1 = [['Pisa','Tower','River','Tuscany'],['London','City','UK','England'],['Berlin','Germany','Munich']]
set_2 = [['Pisa','Arno','River','Tuscany','Florence','London','Tower'],['Germany','German','UBanh'],['London','City','UK','England','Europe']]

pairs = []

for vect_1 in set_1:
    dist = []
    for vect_2 in set_2:
        dist.append(jaccard_similarity(vect_1,vect_2))
    pairs.append(np.argmax(dist))

print(pairs)
```

I know this has O(N^2) time complexity, but I was wondering whether there might be some optimization/heuristic so that the average case would be better.

Similarly, is there something concerning the code itself that I might optimize?

EDIT: I modified the question to make it more precise.

Comment: I'm not sure you can get any better than O(N^2) (by the end of the day, you still have to compare every vector with another one), **but** you can definitely make that O(N^2) faster by using `itertools.product` instead of that nested loop. This will at least push the iteration down to the C level. It might also be possible to take advantage of some numpy vectorization.  Can you provide some example input and output?

Comment: In general, I don't think you can go faster than O(N^2) unless you work in a small dimension. But you can speed up the code by pre-processing: normalize all vectors and consider their inner product as a metric)

Comment: I edited the question. Being more precise I am dealing with the Jaccard distance for a set a words. Now there is a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use scipy.spatial.distance.cdist, which computes the entire matrix for a given metric. The time complexity is unavoidable, but scipy makes it fast.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

Comment: I edited the question. Cdist seems like a good oportunity, but as I've put now in the question I am dealing with lists of words and the Jaccard distance. Cdist expects numeric vectors instead.